# Can someone know the files inside a directory from outside the server?

Tags: php, security

I have web application that will store some files inside a directory called items, and each item will have it's own directory.

The question is if the directory has an index.html page can anyone knows what the names of files might be ?

more explanation

```
 http://www.mysite.com/items/item-734783HH/
```

inside item-734783HH there will be 2 files

```
 -index.html
 -secureFile.zip
```

The `secureFile` name will be hashed. Is there anyway to steal this file from the web ? that's my real concern

Also, I am using `PHP` for copying this file and give it to the user when the purchase is complete.

Comment: They can not know it, but they can guess it, and from my experience,  Google tends to be frighteningly good at that. Also anybody who has access to your browser history could get hold of it, and once the link is published, the file is no longer secure. It's not a great method to secure truly sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

short answer, but only "usually" true: no.

long version for the short version: if you have an index.html then going to `http://www.mysite.com/items/item-734783HH/` will serve up `http://www.mysite.com/items/item-734783HH/index.html` instead. Users will not see a directory listing, so they either have to know those files already exist, or guess them.

actually true answer: only you can tell us. It depends on the server you're using in combination with PHP, and what you've told it to autoresolve to when someone hits a route that does not indicate a file but a directory. It also depends on whether you blacklist/whitelist files based on file patterns, like a "DENY FROM ALL" for files that start with ".", etc.

It's probably time to learn more about how your server works. The internet has a lot of good information on that.